# How to remove randomly selected variables from a list

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and so this might be an easy question but I am unsure how to do it.

I am making a study schedule for myself, but because I know that I will avoid the hard subjects until the last moment I have put the variables into a list that is randomly selected from.

Is there a way to remove each randomly selected item from the list that I made originally so that it cannot be randomly selected again?

Here is my code:

```
subjects = as.list(as.list(rep( c("Biology", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Humanities"), c(47,42,10,12)))

study = as.list(sample(subjects, 1, replace = F))
study
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: if everything is of lengths 1, then you could do: `subjects[!subjects %in% study]`

Answer (score 0):

Data: *(not sure you need to list your vector)*

```
subjects = rep( c("Biology", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Humanities"), c(47,42,10,12))

study = sample(subjects, 1, replace = F)
```

Here is option to achieve this, it will remove the first occurrence of the `study` within your vector of subjects

```
subjects = subjects[-which(subjects == study)[1]]
```

Or you can `sample` your full list to generate a random order:

```
sample(subjects, length(subjects), replace = F)
```